# One entity related to multiple entities

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, entity

I have the 3 following entities.

- Category
- Post
- Sprint

When I am creating an post or sprint I'd really like to place them under a category. But how can I solve this problem by not making 2 separate entities?

I'm confused.

Comment: Add a category column to each of the `Post` and `Sprint` tables.

Comment: This question lacks information and should provide example of what have you tried

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I don't know what was struggling in my mind but that was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Add a category column to each of the Post and Sprint tables. Thanks Gordon Linoff!